# Cannot export all users, only one shows up when Importing-CSV File to then Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell

I've only just started to learn PowerShell but I'm banging my head on the wall with this one. When I Import-CSV a list of users to get the userprincipalname on Get-Aduser with the header SamAccountName, I am able to see all the emails on the console:

```
ForEach ($user in $allUsers)
{ 
Get-ADUser $user.samaccountname -Properties userprincipalname | select -Property userprincipalname
}
```

However, when I try to export them to a csv-file only 1 user comes out. I always have a problem when using a foreach loop for this...

```
ForEach ($user in $allUsers)
{ 
Get-ADUser $user.samaccountname -Properties userprincipalname | select -Property userprincipalname | export-csv $path -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I'm always run into this problem when making my foreach loops. I only ever get or change 1 variable. Why is this? x_X Please help!

And my CSV file has a header of SamAccountName and samaccount names. Without exporting I get good data from this code on the console:

user@test.com
user2@test.com
etc...

Comment: Use the `-Append` parameter to avoid overwriting the Csv on each iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were exporting in each iteration of the loop, which would overwrite the file.  I haven't tried it but the changes below should work.

```
$allUsers  | Foreach-Object { 
    $user = $_ 
    Get-ADUser $user.samaccountname -Properties userprincipalname | select -Property userprincipalname 
} | export-csv $path -NoTypeInformation
```

You must use this syntax vs `foreach(x in y)` if you want to directly pipeline the results to `export-csv`

Comment: Travis, thank you, typing your code in works. Can you explain why using `foreach ($user in $allUsers)
{
Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName -Properties userprincipalname | select -Property userprincipalname
} | export-csv $path -NoTypeInformation` Doesn't work? It says I have an empty pipeline. There seem to be some fundamental difference between typing out foreach, and the way you did yours but what is it? It seems the same to me. Is the way you typed it way more efficient and encompassing? Is your % { a replacement of for each, or is the key using $_ pipeline?

Comment: The main problem is the export is inside the loop... So you are overwriting the file each iteration.   Foreach(x in y) won't work if in a pipeline.  So if you want to use that syntax you'll have to accumulate the results in a collection and pipe the collection to export after the foreach

Comment: The code I just posted above has the export outside the loop right? It's outside the } when I do exactly my last comment, it will say empty pipeline.

Comment: You cannot use foreach(x in y) in a pipeline you must use foreach-object or its alias %